# Api Facebook постинг в публикацию страницы

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

С сайта сделать пост в публикации (страница) , при постинге через API пост попадает почему то в уведомления, причем от моего лица, а не от страницы.
Ни page_id ни group_id не помогает. Подскажите, что не так делаю...

```
$linkData = [

'link' => 'https://yandex.ru',
'message' => 'It works!',
'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!', 
'caption' => "Caption of the Post", 
'description' => 'this is a description',
'picture' => 'https://yandex,ru/logo.jpg',
];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post("/{$page_id}/feed", $linkData, $token);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];`
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно установить приложение Facebook App, указать необходимые базовые данные.

Далее, получить apid, и secret key в самом приложении это все есть.

Далее идем по ссылке https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

У юзера выбираем необходимые права на публикацию постов и групп.

Далее выбираем страницу или группу, для которой нужно получить токен.

Получаем токен, вставляем его в скрипт SDK, пробуем постить.

Также не забывайте указывать, в SDK ссылку на какую именно страницу Вы хотите сделать пост ! Это обычно находится в строке где написан "**'POST', $params);**"